# A question about diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $A \ne0$, but $A^k=0$ for some integer $k \gt1$. show that $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Could somebody give me some hints?Many thanks

Comment: Do you know about jordan normal form and/or Cayley-Hamilton?

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A = PDP^{-1}$ where $P$ is invertible and $D$ is diagonal.  Try to express $A^k$ in terms of $P$ and $D$, and see what you can infer about the entries of $D$ from the equation $A^k = 0$.

Comment: @GitGud I know nothing about them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose it is diagonlisable, then $A = \Lambda D\Lambda^{-1}$, then $D^k = 0$ (why?)

then, given $D$ is diagonal, what is $D$,  so what is $A$?

Comment: So, the entries on diagonal line of D are all zeros right? So then A is zero.

Comment: @user236626 yes so contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If a matrix A is diagonalizable, it means there is some other matrix, let's call it S, such that $D=SAS^-1$ is a diagonal matrix (e.g. it has all nonzero values in the diagonal entries and 0 everywhere else).

But $A^k=0$.

But then $D^k=SAS^-1SAS^-1...SAS^-1SAS^-1=SA^kS^-1=0$.

But $D^k$ can't equal 0, because it is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: ${\rm diag}(0,0,\ldots,0)$ is a diagonal matrix. The point is it must be nonzero.